# CLICompanion equivalent for rpm-based linux?

Tags: linux, terminal

There's a nice program for linux terminal beginners - CLICompanion - terminal with tips and dictionary. It's distributed only with deb packages. I'm just wondering if there's rpm package for this program?

Answer (score 0):

http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/alien/
Use this to convert the packakge.

Comment: doesn't work - python dependencies

Comment: Can't you install the python dependencies?